# is pfSense suited for my setup?

Tags: networking, pfsense

I have a fairly large home network that consists of:

- 2 wired PCs,
- 3 Smartphones,
- 1 Tablet,
- 2 wireless PCs
- 2 wired gaming consoles
- 2 wireless gaming consoles

The problem is that I think that my router has problems handling all the traffic that this generates, since it crashes (reboots, no more WAN, etc.) every once in a while. I have an old machine here, a couple NICs, and a switch. Would it make sense to get that box to run pfSense and distribute traffic across different NICs (1 to switch for wired, 1 to router (as AP) for wireless)?

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pfSense would work, although likely overkill.

Try DD-WRT first, if you can. Your current router may support it.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Comment: I did try DD-WRT on a WRT54G we had, and that did not fix the problem. Maybe I missed a configuration somewhere?

Comment: Its odd that you'd still have the issue with DD-WRT on that router. I've run it in much larger environments with success. Possibly a bad router or poor internet connection?  pfSense would be a good next step then if you have the hardware already.

Comment: It is odd, as I have seen DD-WRT perform well in large scale deployments as well. Maybe it actually was the router. I'll try DD-WRT on this one, and move to pfSense if that does not fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I used to be an IT consultant, I've put DD-WRT in near 50 SMB office environments and have had near 0 issues, usually on that same WRT54G (or the WRT54G-L). I've also had great success with PFsense too, i set it up for my current work as well as a couple of my larger clients.

Comment: Running DD-WRT atm on the new WRT400N we have over here, and everything is going well. I'm guessing the 54G was bogus! Thanks again!